# Magento 2 Custom module installation time create media directory

Tags: magento2, permissions, install-script, file-permissions, directory

I want to create media directory with 777 recursive permission on custom module installation time, So I have created `createDirectory` function in `InstallSchema`.
But currently directory is created with `drwxrwxr-x` permission. so i want to give `777` permission.

Here is my `InstallSchema.php`.

```
<?php

/**
 * VendorNameSpace ModuleName
 * Class Description
 */

namespace VendorNameSpace\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface {

    /**
     * Blog Post Module's Media Directories
     */
    const MEDIA_TMP_PATH = 'vendornamespace/modulename/tmp/upload';
    const MEDIA_PATH = 'vendornamespace/modulename/upload';

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    private $_directoryList;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File 
     */
    private $_ioFile;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $ioFile
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $ioFile,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
    ) {
        $this->_ioFile = $ioFile;
        $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup, 
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {

        $this->_createMediaDir();


        /**
         * Database Script
         *
         *
         *  ......
         */

    }

    /**
     * Creating Media Directories
     */
    protected function _createMediaDir() {

        $mediaTemp = $this->_directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . SELF::MEDIA_TMP_PATH;
        $media = $this->_directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . SELF::MEDIA_PATH;

        $directories = [$media, $mediaTemp];
        $ioAdapter = $this->_ioFile;

        foreach ($directories as $dir) {
            if(!is_dir($dir)){
                $ioAdapter->mkdir($dir,0777);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I found the solution by giving parent directory to recursive permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the exact way to make it accessible for everyone you have to give `0777` permission after creating.

You have to additionally add `chmodRecursive` of `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File` function to give parent directory `0777`.

```
protected function _createMediaDir() {

    $mainMediaDir = "vendornamespace"; // you can put it also as constant as below directory
    $mediaTemp = $this->_directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . SELF::MEDIA_TMP_PATH;
    $media = $this->_directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . SELF::MEDIA_PATH;

    $directories = [$media, $mediaTemp];
    $ioAdapter = $this->_ioFile;

    foreach ($directories as $dir) {
        // Use `checkAndCreateFolder` instead of mkdir so it will check if directory available or not
        $ioAdapter->checkAndCreateFolder($dir);
    }

    // Give recursive permission to main media directory That's it!..
    $ioAdapter::chmodRecursive($mainMediaDir, 0777);
    $ioAdapter->close();

    return true;
}
```